# Обрезать видео до нужного размера через FFMpeg

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

собрали такой код для того, чтобы вытащить превью видео, но они сохраняются слишком больших размеров, нужно обрезать его сразу же при получении этого превью

```
$FFMpeg = env("FFMPEG_BINARIES")." -i \"".$path_file."\" -an -ss 0.001 -y -f mjpeg \"".$path_file_out."\" 2>&1";
$FFMpeg = exec($FFMpeg, $outpuths);
```

Как в этот код добавить размер 200х250, чтобы это превью обрезалось до этих размеров?

Comment: На каком языке программирования ваш код? Пожалуйста, [укажите язык в метках к вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1515050/edit).

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan добавил

Comment: Обрезалось или уменьшилось?

Comment: @andreymal уменьшилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$FFMpeg = env("FFMPEG_BINARIES")." -i \"".$path_file."\" -an -ss 0.001 -y -s 200x250 -f mjpeg \"".$path_file_out."\" 2>&1";
$FFMpeg = exec($FFMpeg, $outpuths);
```